# `page-break` for `<ol>` with custom counters

Tags: html, css

I am using these styles to create `<ol>`s that use letters in parentheses.

```css
  ol.letters {
    counter-reset: list;
  }
  ol.letters > li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
  }
  ol.letters > li::before {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: -1.75rem;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    counter-increment: list;
    content: "(" counter(list, lower-alpha) ") ";
  }
```

It works perfectly, except for when I try to print the page. There tends to be page breaks between the counter and the content as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsQTO.png).

```
  (b)

  ============ page-break ============

       This is stuff for (b).
```

I've tried adding `break-after/break-before: avoid` to `li::before` and `li` and `li > *:first-child`, but neither works. I would also like to avoid `@counter-style`. How do I make it so that the counter and content are never separated?

```
  ============ page-break ============

  (b)  This is stuff for (b).
```

Comment: You need to tag whatever that is. It's not plain CSS.

Comment: changed to plain CSS